# Represent a protobuf map as a json

Tags: grpc, proto, protobufjs

I'm using [grpcc](https://github.com/njpatel/grpcc), which is based on protobuf.js, to test my grpc service APIs.

My `.proto` file:

```
message MyRequest {
    string userId = 1;
    map<string, string> params = 2;
}
```

I tried the following json body to send a request:

```
{userId : "my_user_id" , params: { name: "my_name"}}
{userId : "my_user_id" , params: [{"name":"my_name"}] }
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Error: Illegal value for Message.Field....MyRequest.params of type string: object (expected ProtoBuf.Map or raw object for map field)
```

How to correctly represent a protobuf map as a json?

Comment: Have you tried using just an object, instead of an array of objects?

Comment: yes I tried this since that didn't work. I added both cases I tried.

Comment: Here's protobuf's javascript map class.
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/js/map.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper json body would be the following:

`{ "userId": "my_user_id", "params": { "name": "my_name" } }`

What you've tried doing is an array of maps, which doesn't really mean anything in the context of protobuf. A `map<string, string>` is exactly the description of a json object, so more than one value would be represented the following way:

`{ "params": { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" } }`

No need for an array.

Comment: I already tried this way. still the same error. I added the both cases I tried

Comment: Maybe this is tied to grpcc then. Protobuf maps really do translate into plain objects in JavaScript when used with protobufjs and grpc. I've been using this property in my grpc project for a while now.